# How to stop getting duplicates on my sudoku grid?

Tags: python, data-structures, sudoku

I've coded everything to the point where my program tries to solve the sudoku by itself, but when I run it I'm getting duplicates on the grid. I know that the problem lies on the part where the code checks each 3x3 grid but I can't find the problem.

This is all my code:

```py
grid2 = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0], [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0], [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3], [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1], [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6], [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0], [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5], [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]
   
def valid(grid,x,y,n):
    for i in range (9):
        if(grid[x][i] == n):
            return False
    return True
   
    for i in range(9):
        if(grid[y][i] == n):
            return False
    return True
   
    x //= 3
    y //= 3
    
    for i in range (3):
        for j in range(3):
            if(grid[x+i][y+j] == n):
                return False
    return True
       

def sudoku(grid):
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if(grid[x][y] == 0):
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if(valid(grid,x,y,n)):
                        grid[x][y] = n
                        result = sudoku(grid)
                        if result is not None:
                            return result
                        grid[x][y] = 0
                return
    return grid
```

I tried to change the values of the x and y to see if its checking if [x,y] in each grid, but couldn't find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the problem was with my for loops to check the 3x3 as I was not multiplying the x's and y's by 3. Adding that fixed the issue where the 3x3 would not be checked completely. The other problem with my code was the "if result is not None" statement. I removed it and it would iterate through the sudoku completely, and in the if statement where valid was called, I added another statement that would check if the sudoku didn't have any 0's left.
Here is the code that worked:

```
def valid(grid,x,y,n):
#Checks row
if n in grid[x]:
    return False
#Checks columns
for row in grid:
   if(row[y] == n):
       return False

x //= 3
y //= 3
#Checks each square
for i in range (3):
    for j in range(3):
        if(grid[x*3+i][y*3+j] == n):
            return False
return True

def sudoku(grid):
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        if(grid[x][y] == 0):
            for n in range(1,10):
                if(valid(grid,x,y,n)):
                    grid[x][y] = n
                    result = sudoku(grid)
                    if np.count_nonzero(result) == 81:
                        return result
                        return result
                    grid[x][y] = 0
            return grid
return grid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `valid` function unconditionally returns `True` after the first loop (assuming it doesn't `return False` within that loop). The rest of the function will *never* run, so as long as that first loop passes (confirming the number isn't in the row), you consider it valid, without ever checking the column or the 3x3 sub-box. Get rid of all but the last `return True` in that function.

This will still leave you with other problems (e.g. your first and second loop are checking *exactly* the same thing, where I suspect you meant to check the row in one and the column in the other), but you'll get closer.

---

Side-notes on simplifying the code:

A row is a single sub-`list`; you could replace the very first loop entirely with a simple membership test in that sub-`list` (same big-O, but in practice, *much* faster to let Python do the work for you in a single opcode):

```
if n in grid[x]:
    return False
```

The second loop has to be more complex (because you need to check a single cell on each of multiple rows), but you can still avoid quite so much indexing via direct iteration, so after fixing, it's:

```
for row in grid:     # Direct iteration, faster than index loop, gives a useful name,
    if row[y] == n:  # and simpler usage
        return False
```

Comment: The first and the second loop are checking the same because I have: grid[y][i] == n. When I'm supposed to flip the y and the i right?

Comment: @Armenta: Yeah. But as I mention in my updated answer, both loops can simplify dramatically, and remove some of that confusion (by getting rid of a lot of the manual indexing entirely).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a more concise approach using a set.  There are 27 groups of numbers in a sudoku board that need have mutually exclusive (unique) numbers in them.  Each position is part of 3 of these groups (row, column and block).

So you can first create a function that will produce a set of tuples representing the 3 entries (group,number) for a given number at a specific position:

```
def sudoSet(r,c,n,base=3):
    side = base*base
    return { (r//base*base+c//base,n), (r+side,n), (c+2*side,n) }
```

You can then use this function to obtain the set of used exclusions for a whole board (ignoring positions containing a zero):

```
def sudoSets(board,base=3):
    return set.union(*(sudoSet(r,c,n,base) 
                       for r,row in enumerate(board)
                       for c,n in enumerate(row) if n ))
```

Using these two function, checking if a number can be placed at a given position becomes a simple set operation:

```
grid2 = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
         [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
         [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
         [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
         [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
         [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
         [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
         [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
         [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]

used = sudoSets(grid2)
print(sudoSet(7,2,3).isdisjoint(used) ) # True, a 3 can be placed at 7,2
print(sudoSet(7,2,6).isdisjoint(used) ) # False, a 6 cannot be placed at 7,2
```

This approach lets you easily track placement and removal of number on the board for expansion and backtracking:

```
# place 3 at 7,2:

grid2[7][2] = 3
used |= sudoSet(7,2,3)

# remove 3 placed at 7,2:

used -= sudoSet(7,2,grid2[7][2])
grid2[7][2] = 0
```

You can also use this to validate if a whole grid is valid ( the size of the used set should be exactly 3 times the number of non-zero numbers in the grid):

```
isValid = len(used) == 3*sum(len(r)-r.count(0) for r in grid2)
```

With these functions and a set based approach, a brute force solver can be written in just a few lines:

```
def sudoSolve(board):
    solution = [row.copy() for row in board]    # prepare solution
    used     = sudoSets(board)                  # track preset numbers
    empties  = [(r,c) for r,row in enumerate(board)
                      for c,n   in enumerate(row) if not n ] # pos to fill
    e,inc = 0,0
    while 0 <= e+inc < len(empties):
        e    += inc                             
        r,c   = empties[e]                      # position to assign
        if inc < 0:                             # unexclude previous attempt
            used -= sudoSet(r,c,solution[r][c])
        solution[r][c] += 1                     # try next value
        if solution[r][c] > 9:                  # All tried 
            solution[r][c] = 0                  # clear number for later
            inc = -1                            # backtrack position
            continue
        posSet = sudoSet(r,c,solution[r][c])    # position/number groups
        if posSet.isdisjoint(used):             # no conflict            
            used |= posSet                      # track exclusions
            inc = 1                             # next empty position
        else:
            inc = 0                             # try other at position
    return solution if inc >= 0 else []
```

output:

```
print(*sudoSolve(grid2),sep="\n")

[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
[6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8]
[1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3]
[4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1]
[7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6]
[9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4]
[2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue adjust calculation of x and y like this in 'value' function:

```
grid2 = [[5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0], [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0], [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0], [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3], [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1], [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6], [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0], [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5], [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]]

def valid(grid, x, y, n):
    for i in range(9):
        if grid[x][i] == n:
            return False

    for i in range(9):
        if grid[i][y] == n:
            return False

    # Calculate the starting row and column for the 3x3 subgrid
    x_start = (x // 3) * 3
    y_start = (y // 3) * 3

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[x_start + i][y_start + j] == n:
                return False

    return True

def sudoku(grid):
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            if(grid[x][y] == 0):
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if(valid(grid,x,y,n)):
                        grid[x][y] = n
                        result = sudoku(grid)
                        if result is not None:
                            return result
                        grid[x][y] = 0
                return
    return grid
sudoku(grid2)
```